# PHP - Bringing and utilizing variables from one page to another

Tags: php, html, variables

I am a real beginner at this so sorry if I am makin awfull mistakes!

Want I want to do I know is very simple but I cant find the relevant help in my documentation.

I want to bring four variables out of a 'product' page, I then want to post these as the values of an html form but I am not sure how.

The variables come from managebooks.php and need to be used in ammendbook.php.

In managebooks.php my link to ammendbook.php is as follows:

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";
echo "<a href='amendbook.php?bookname=".$bookname."&bookauthor=".$bookauthor."&bookpub=".$bookpub."&bookisbn=".$bookisbn."'>Amend Entry</a>";
echo "</td>";
```

This i expected to bring that four variables with me to the next page (ammendbook.php) my form code is as follows:

```
<form id="adminlogin" name="login" action="amendbookupdate.php" method="post">
                    Book Title <br />
                    <input type="text" name="booktitle" value="<?php echo $bookname; ?>"></input><br />
                    Book Author(s)<br />
                    <input type="text" name="bookauthor" value="<?php echo $bookauthor; ?>"></input><br />
                    Book Publisher<br />
                    <input type="text" name="bookpub" value="<?php echo $bookpub; ?>" ></input><br />
                    ISBN-10 number (non-standard format)<br />
                    <input type="text" name="bookisbn" value="<?php echo $bookisbn; ?>"></input><br /><br />
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value=" - Update Database - "></input>
                </form>
```

I am not sure what else to include, I tried making an array to see if that would work (hense the echo variables like this:

```
<?php
    $bookname['bookname'] = $_GET['bookname'];
    $bookauthor['bookauthor'] = $_GET['bookauthor'];
    $bookpub['bookpub'] = $_GET['bookpub'];
    $bookisbn['bookisbn'] = $_GET['bookisbn'];
?>
```

But this is wrong.

I also in the form attempted to just put:

```
<input type="text" name="booktitle" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['bookname'] ?>"></input><br />
```

but this is also wrong!

Any ideas guys..

Thank you in advance for reading and any help!

[=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try:

```
$bookname = $_GET['bookname'];
$bookauthor = $_GET['bookauthor'];
$bookpub = $_GET['bookpub'];
$bookisbn = $_GET['bookisbn'];
```

At the top of ammendbook.php and then refer to those variables by those names. Is that not what you're looking for? I may be confused.

**Edit:** You should always sanitize variables that come from the GET or POST arrays before assigning them to variables.

Comment: Thats fantastic thank you! Feel very silly but hey... Im learning! I will give your answer a tick when the timer allows me too; Thank you!!

Comment: No problem. Don't feel silly, these are the kinds of things that take some time to learn but that you eventually take for granted.

Answer (score 4):

```
method="post"
```

To

```
method="GET"
```

Then feel free to use

```
$_GET['bookpub']
```

Without declaring.

### FOR EXAMPLE:

**test1.php:**

```
<form action="test2.php" method="get">
Book Title <br />
<input type="text" name="booktitle" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value=" - Update Database - " />
</form>
```

**test2.php**

```
<body>
<? echo $_GET["booktitle"]; ?>
</body>
```

Comment: I think these are good points that the questioner should take into consideration, but I think his question was more about how to get the variables from page 1 to page 2 (page 2 being the page with the form on it) using $_GET. The points you make are definitely valid when it comes to getting from page 2 to page 3 (the page with teh form to whatever page is processing the form).

Comment: Thank you for you responce, I used the above answer but I am keeping a keen eye upon yours now I am processing the form! Thank you very much! [=